# 'mdb-range-input' is not a known element. If 'mdb-range-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular8, mdbootstrap

I try to md bootstrap slider in this way:

```
<mdb-range-input (rangeValueChange)="onRangeValueChange($event)" id="range" min="0" max="100"></mdb-range-input>
```

I have set in the module in imports section:

`MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),`

and in angular.json:

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ],
        "styles": [
         "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/assets/sass/paper-kit.scss",
          "src/assets/css/demo.css",
          "src/assets/css/nucleo-icons.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
"node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
"node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/mdb.scss",
"node_modules/animate.css/animate.css"
        ],
```

however I get error like shown below. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'mdb-range-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'mdb-range-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mdb-range-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Answer (score 0):

You use MDB Angular Free (angular-bootstrap-md). The mdb-range-input is PRO component and is not available in this package.